# syslog and kern.log files are massive

Tags: syslog, ubuntu-20.04

I got a warning that my PC was running out of space and noticed that /var/log had taken up nearly 190 Gb. On further inspection, noticed that the kern.log and syslog files are massive, after running `du -sh *|grep G`

Currently running Ubuntu 20.04.

What is the reason for this and is it safe to delete these log files?

[Screenshot of log file sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmywC.png)

Comment: You should, perhaps, open them... And, yes, they are safe to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks ! Deleted them, had some WiFi driver issues that got resolved when i updated to the latest Ubuntu version. That seems to have been the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple steps to clean and create both syslog and kern.log

Create a sh file eg. **refresh.sh** and save the following code.

```
echo "" > /var/log/kern.log
echo "" > /var/log/syslog
service syslog restart
journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
```

run it as root eg. ***sudo sh refresh.sh***

It will clear the logs from

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/kern.log
/run/log/journal
```

Comment: Another way might useful if an user cannot login to the system due to full memory occupied by these logs. Create as well as start with bootable linux and Now go to the folder ( /var/log/ ) and delete the files kern.log and syslog and do not forget to create those new blank files with the same  name (syslog and kern.log ). Restart the system and Remove the bootable device and your system is ready.

Comment: Detailed steps with some screenshot for beginners 
 https://medium.com/@abdullah.farwees/syslog-journal-and-kern-log-files-size-are-huge-ab98883c1099